# Insert text at cursor position in Embarcadero Tools API

Tags: c++, delphi, toolsapi

I'm writing an extension for the Embarcadero C++ Builder IDE and want to programmatically insert text inside the code editor at the cursor position. I searched the Tools API header files but only found an interface which allows me to insert text at the start of the editor.

Is there any interface or function which allows me to insert text at a specified position? And if so, can you provide me a code example?

I'm writing the extension in C++, but code examples in Delphi will do too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this document by Bruno Fierens, [Extending the Delphi IDE](https://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/extending-the-delphi-ide.pdf):

```
var
  EditorServices: IOTAEditorServices;
  EditView: IOTAEditView;
  copyright: string;
begin
  copyright := '{ Copyright © 2011 by tmssoftware.com }';
  EditorServices := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAEditorServices;

  EditView := EditorServices.TopView;

  if Assigned(EditView) then
  begin
    // position cursor at 1,1
    EditView.Buffer.EditPosition.Move(1,1);
    // insert copyright notice on top
    EditView.Buffer.EditPosition.InsertText(copyright);
  end;
end;
```

Using `EditView.Buffer.EditPosition.Move()` you should be able to freely move the cursor to any location.